# Cleaning Up Boot Details?? Dual Boot (UEFI) : Windows 8 & Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader

Well, I don't know from where to begin with...
I've a DELL Laptop(x64 Based Processor) with Windows 8 Pre-installed!

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my system.(i don't know if it suports UEFI or not).
I used a 32-bit Ubuntu ISO(somewhere I read that it can be used on both x64 & 32bit processors for installation) but later saw in some blogs/forum that for dual boot purpose, one has to use the 64-bit ISO image for 64bit processor.

My system had UEFI with SecureBoot enabled!

By hit and trial, i somehow(legacy/uefi, secureboot on/off) managed to install Ubuntu on my lappy on a separate partition on the same HD at that time.
But i couldn't open my Windows 8, i'd to change some boot options, in order to open it. It was troublesome.
I was not able to get GRUB Bootloader menu at all.

But to this point, I think what i accidentally did was:
"My Windows 8 was installed on UEFI Secure Boot:ON option & afterwards I installed the ubuntu on LEGACY Mode Secure Boot:OFF."

Since things weren't working well then, so i just deleted the Ubuntu drive, formatted it with NTFS fs and used for windows drive and turned the UEFI Mode, SecureBoot:ON
My Windows 8 started working fine and it gets open as usual.

Now the thing is:
I've some small partition named as 'biosgrub' still, and if i turn to 'Legacy Mode';
Nothing gets loaded, and I get a "grub rescue" prompt. I don't know what to do with it.

Can I rectify all this??

I think there's will be multiple bootloaders in there probably, if I go to install Ubuntu again. Which won't be good at all, I presume?

Is it possible to clean all this up, and do a fresh Ubuntu(14.04) install alongside Windows 8?

I know this is a complete mess, but can I do anything about it...
I just want Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8, in UEFI mode..ie atleast a bootloader screen prompting me to open either windows or ubuntu..

Comment: If your Windows is UEFI, why would you ever change to CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode. And if you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode then it will not show in UEFI mode. And 32 bit is BIOS only, only 64 bit will work with UEFI.

Comment: Because, my USB Drive containing the bootable Ubuntu was not at all detectable in UEFI mode. It was coming under the boot device options only when I changed  system Boot Mode to 'Legacy'

Comment: Some Dell need extra settings in UEFI.  Not just for Precision models: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/11/14/ubuntu-on-the-precision-m3800.aspx AND:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z

Comment: A lot of people enable BIOS/CSM/legacy mode because there are loads of blogs, forum posts, etc., that recommend doing so. They're wrong to do so, but it's a tidal wave of wrongness. Other people do it because they fiddle and it gets them past an initial hurdle. Then they find two or three other hurdles are waiting for them....

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete the BIOS Boot Partition (which `parted`, GParted, and some other tools identify as a "bios_grub" partition). There will still be GRUB's first-stage boot loader installed in the disk's MBR, but if it's not causing problems for you, it's safer to leave that alone.

With that done, you can try again. Two sites with reasonable advice are:

- [My Web page on doing EFI-mode Linux installs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the same subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Ignore any page that recommends enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy mode (or, equivalently, disabling EFI/UEFI support), except as a last resort. That's the hard way to do it, but this bad method has, sadly, gained a significant foothold on the Web.